# Catastrophic Failure when accessing ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp

In our app, we're getting a significant number of exceptions thrown when trying to access `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()`. We're essentially trying to change the title of the window depending on the state of the app.

```
try
{
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "Custom title";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // ex.message = Catastrophic Failure!
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens sometimes? What do we need to check for before accessing the current view?

Comment: Can you post a small sample project? Can't reproduce.

Comment: @Bart, that's the issue. I can't replicate it. I have this try-catch in our code and reporting the contents of the exception back to base. We have thousands of users a day and we get a lot of these exceptions. I don't know what state the app is in where `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()` fails.

Comment: it might happend if runs from not UI thread (?)

Comment: Hi @AlexejSommer, yes I already checked if that's the case. The title is being changed from a button event and I checked for dispatcher access just to be sure.

Comment: Have you published your app to Windows Store? Could you share app link so that we can test it? Health report in Dev Center dashboard may also helpful.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, it's called Drawboard PDF.